# Find and replace with a regular expression in a text file

Tags: regex, vbscript, jenkins

I am building a jenkins jobs for build comparison. I want to replace **double newline (\n\n) in the text file with single new line (\n)**. After that I want to replace every instance of **word "commit" with a newline and commit i.e "\ncommit"**. I want to use a **vbscript** for this, anyone can suggest how to do this?

Currently I am using following VBScript:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

strName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
strOriginal = Wscript.Arguments(1)
strReplacement = Wscript.Arguments(2)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strName, ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

' Replace desired string
Set objRegExp = New RegExp
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = False
objRegExp.Pattern = strOriginal
strReplacement = objRegExp.Replace(strText, strReplacement)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strName, ForWriting)
objFile.Write strReplacement
objFile.Close
```

The script replaces regex patterns with a normal string, i.e. it replaces double newline with a normal string i.e with string `\n`. I don't know how to extend this to replace regex with regex.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Currently I am using a VBScript which replaces regex with a normal pattern i.e it is inserting string "\n" instead oof double new line. I don't how to extend the script to replace regex with regex as I am new to VBScript. I am using following script:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are overkill for this. Use two string replacements:

```vb
strText = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strName, ForReading).ReadAll

strText = Replace(strText, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)
strText = Replace(strText, "commit", vbLf & "commit")

objFSO.OpenTextFile(strName, ForWriting).Write strText
```